# Error: unknown type in C. What can be the reason when all required header files are included?

Tags: c

So I cannot figure out the following problem:
I am getting unknown type for orderPtr which is typedef of struct Order even though I have included the header file that declares this type.
Here is the code in queue.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include "book.h"
#include "queue_node.h"

/*
 * Queue structure for consumers threads
 */
typedef struct queue {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t notempty;
    struct queue_node *rear;
} queuePtr;

void queue_enqueue(queuePtr *, orderPtr *);

orderPtr *queue_dequeue(queuePtr *queue);


#endif
```

and here this type is declared in book.h:

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "uthash.h"
#include "customer.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "queue.h"

typedef struct order {
    char *title;
    double price;
    char *idnum;
    char *category;
} orderPtr;

void order_destroy(orderPtr *);
orderPtr * order_create(char *, double, char *, char *);

#endif
```

[image]

Comment: You have a circular reference, `book.h` includes `queue.h` and `queue.h` includes `book.h`. I'm not quite sure what you expect the compiler to do about that :)

Comment: this part of the struct definition: '} queuePtr;' is NOT generating a pointer to struct type, but rather a struct type.  You could change the line to: '} *queuePtr;  --or-- your could invoke the function: void order_destroy(orderPtr *); using order_destroy( &myOrder );  where myOrder is the instance of the struct

Comment: in a linked list, the pointer to the next entry in the list should be the same type struct as the struct itself,  so this line: struct queue_node *rear; would be expected to be: struct queue *rear;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the include chain, it's like this:

1. `main.c` includes `book.h`
2. `book.h` includes `queue.h` at the top (before the typedef of `orderPtr`)
3. `queue.h` tries to use `orderPtr` which has not yet been typedef'd = error
4. Finally comes the typedef of `orderPtr`.

You can get around this in several ways.  One way is that in `queue.h` you can do:

```
/*
 * Queue structure for consumers threads
 */
typedef struct queue {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t notempty;
    struct queue_node *rear;
} queuePtr;

struct orderPtr;  // Forward declaration

// The use of struct orderPtr * is allowed because it is a pointer.
// If it wasn't a pointer, it would be an error because the size
// would be unknown.
void queue_enqueue(queuePtr *, struct orderPtr *);

struct orderPtr *queue_dequeue(queuePtr *queue);
```